# Differential ADC reference plane - ground or midpoint?

Tags: pcb-design, adc, ground-plane

The Microchip (ex-Atmel) [ATSAMD10](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAMD10D14) has a 12-bit SAR ADC with the option to use differential input. I'm generating a virtual ground (\$V_\mathrm{mid}\$) at the midpoint (512 mV) of the reference voltage (1.024 V), with the input signal centered around that.

[image]

My question is regarding the reference plane for the analog section preceding the ADC. There is a simple 2nd order low-pass Sallen-Key for anti-aliasing, and a placeholder for another RC filter after the Sallen-Key. Should the plane beneath the analog section be ground, or \$V_\mathrm{mid}\$? My feeling is that it should be \$V_\mathrm{mid}\$ as the filters are all connected to that reference voltage. The only ground connections in that region are for the opamp power.

[image]

This is for a two layer board, currently with a ground pour on the bottom layer (green) with some \$V_\mathrm{mid}\$ traces through for routing. All the analog inputs are on the bottom of the microcontroller at the top left.

[image]

The system is not particularly demanding, but (notional, given the ADC's performance) LSB performance would be nice.

- Source impedance: 18 \$\Omega\$
- \$V_\mathrm{LSB}\$: 250 \$\mu V\$
- \$f_c\$: 1.25 kHz
- \$f_s\$: 4.096 kHz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It (almost) doesn't matter what voltage the plane is at, as it will only be capacitatively coupled.

The important thing is to use the lowest impedance domain so it can rapidly absorb/source charge.  This is usually your "ground".

12 bits, at your voltage and frequency...use ground and you should be good to go.

Comment: My analog days were dual supply, so I was uncertain about this - makes sense, it's just dumping things to any fixed low impedance. I'll wait a bit before `accepting` in case there are other thoughts, but otherwise all good :)

Comment: @awjlogan I think gnd too. Your mid-bias is going to have a decoupling caps anyways, right? From your divider output (or opamp output buffering the divider)?

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes - thanks, that's a good point, there's no decoupling on the output from the voltage reference at the moment. I don't want to put a capacitor on the output of the buffer opamp, as it'll need a series resistor for stability and I don't want to up its impedance. So 0 V ground is the current front runner.

Comment: @awjlogan I meant to say "decoupling cap from divider/buffer output to each rail"

Comment: @DKNguyen Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Are you suggesting a cap from VMID_BUF (top schematic) to +3V3 and 0 V?

Comment: @awjlogan1.024V and 0V. It sounds like you have more experience than me though.

Comment: @DKNguyen hmm, there's `C17` on the voltage divider, but I hadn't considered anything on the buffer output. There is the risk of the opamp becoming unstable with those in place, or I have got the wrong idea about that?

Comment: @awjlogan I don't think necessarily wrong. I put those on dividers generating a mid supply but maybe not needed with opamps due to the low output impedance. Yeah, maybe not.